# Laravel Eloquent Model toJson method does not work recursively

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have read [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json) that this method should be recursive but it doesnt apply to model attributes:

**Table Migration**

```
Schema::create('test', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('test');
    $table->json('testJson')->nullable();

});
```

**Execution**

```
Test::findOrFail($id)->get()->toJson();
```

**Response**

```
{
 id:0,
 test:'',
 testJson:'[{}]' //as string! i need array of objects.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use it and not just watch it, you can always do this:

```
$test = Test::findOrFail($id)->get()->toJson();
```

and just use `json_decode($test->testJson);` to get it as array.

Or if you really really  want it in the place of the json string use this:

`$test = Test::findOrFail($id)->get()->toJson()`;

```
$test['testJson'] = json_decode($test->testJson)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i knew you can do it that way,i think that i misunderstand the documentation about recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out about [attribute-casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) in eloquent models.

In model you can specify how the attribute will be converted when you update or retrive it.

**Model**

```
class Test extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'testJson' => 'object',
    ];
}
```

**Reponse**

```
{
 id:0,
 test:'',
 testJson:[{}] //as json!.
}
```

Which is a bit weird,it should be done by automatic on json type columns.